# Execute a .sql File from cmd to IBM server (db2)

Tags: cmd, db2

I'm trying to import a .sql file into IBM db2 Server using cmd

Here is my cmd line prompt that I'm using

```
cmd /c db2  -u<USER> -h<HOST> -p<PASSWORD> -D<DATABASE> <<My File Repository>/<FileName>.sql
```

Is this cmd prompt correct or not?

Available to give more informations

Comment: What environment and Db2 platform? "db2" is the command line processor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is frequently asked, so do your research.

With `cmd.exe` on MS-Windows, you cannot use such syntax, because the Db2 clp does not accept arguments like `-u ... -h... -p... -D...`.

Instead there are other ways to achieve what you need.

If the Db2-database is on the same hostname as your clp (i.e. is is a local database), then you can use `db2 connect to DATABASENAME` and then use `db2 -tvf filename.sql`. When the database is remote (on a different hostname from your clp), you must supply a userid/password (or certificate, or token, depending on Server configuration)and the remote database has to be pre-catalogued locally (either via XML file or via catalog commands). With local databases you do not need to specify either a userid or a password, it will connect as the currently logged in operating-system user.

If you prefer to use a connection-string, you can rework your scripts to be compatible with the [CLPplus](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clpplus-command) program which is a java app that accepts arguments on its command line.  For people who are familiar with Oracle SQL*Plus, this is often their go-to tool when using Db2.

If you *really* want to use cmd.exe with the Db2 clp to run SQL scripts (for both local **and** remote databases) , then you can do it if you are prepared to first perform some basic configuration steps. You have a choice of old style catlog configuration steps, or XML file.

The old style actions are: `catalog tcpip node`,  then `catalog database` on that node, then `db2 termainate` and finally connect to the remote catalogued database with `db2 connect to $database user XXXX using YYYY` and `db2 -tvf filename.sql`.  You can also have the connect statement inside the SQL script.  All of these actions are well documented in the Db2 Knowledge Center online, so do your research.

If you do not wish to perform the catalog actions, you can also have a pre-prepared XML file (called `db2dsdriver.cfg`) which contains all of the connection details for all Data-Source-Names and databases you use. You can either create the XML file manually, or programatically with the [db2cli](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2cli-db2-interactive-cli) tool and its command line. The IBM supplied CLI drivers for Db2 read and interpret that file at runtime.  This lets you connect to local and remote DSNs without the need to use explicit catalog actions because the XML file has all the details. The CLP will then let you run scripts against those DSNs. This file is documented in the Db2 Knowledge Centre, and can be located (by defailt) in the CLI driver cfg directory, or anywhere via the environment variable `DB2DSDRIVER_CFG_PATH`. Refer to the documentation for all details.

If your remote database runs on Db2-for-i,  or Db2-for-z/os then **different** considerations apply. First IBM supplied CLI drivers both require a license before the connect will succeed. Refer to documentation. Second, for Db2-for i (as/400), you should only consider using the separate IBM product for IBM i series access and its odbc option.

If your remote Db2-database is on Linux/Unix/Windows/zLinux/cloud then you do not need any license locally.

Comment: Hi, thanks you are right my the Db2-database is on remote server . What is the command to connect to remote Db2_database in windows ?

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer . I get it so  , the db2dsdriver.cfg is put where exactly ?